# Finding the general term of a number pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is the number pattern 
15, 29, 56, 108, 208, ... 
The pattern is as follows,

1. Term 1 = $15$ ,
2. Term 2 = Term $1 \times 2 - 1 = 15 \times 2 - 1 = 29 $,
3. Term 3 = Term $2 \times 2 - 2 = 29 \times 2 - 2 = 56 $,
4. Term 4 = Term $3 \times 2 - 4 = 56 \times 2 - 4 =108 $,
5. Term 5 = Term $4 \times 2 - 8=108 \times 2 - 8 =208 $,
6. Term $n$ = Term $(n-1) \times 2 - 2^{n-2}$ ,

How to express $T_n$ algebraically?

Comment: Looks like you are almost there, $T(n)=2T(n-1)-2^{n-2}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T_n=2T_{n-1}-2^{n-1}$$

Let $T_m=2^mP_m\implies P_1=\dfrac{T_1}2=?$

$$2^nP_n=2(2^{n-1}P_{n-1})-2^{n-1}$$

$$\iff P_n=P_{n-1}-\dfrac12=\cdots=P_{n-r}-\dfrac r2$$

Set $r=n-1$

Comment: Oh, thnks man. There's actually a mistake, line 1, Tn = 2 x Term (n-1) - 2^(n-2), but after subbing in the correct expression, I got the answer